# Header Location for relative path

Tags: php

Im working on a basic form and I want to redirect the user to a custom error page if there login details they entered are incorrect. However, whenever I setup the Header location function all it does is refresh the page its currently on. I get this is a stupidly simple question but I can't figure out why my page isn't doing what I want it to do.

```php
if ($rows == 1) {
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 header("Location: dashboard.php");
 } else {
   header("Location: retry.php");
 }
```

Comment: `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Call the exit() function.

```php
if ($rows == 1) {
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   header("Location: dashboard.php");
   exit();
} else {
   header("Location: retry.php");
   exit();
}
```